# Converting String to List of Bytes

Tags: vb.net

This has to be incredibly simple, but I must not be looking in the right place.

I'm receiving this string via a FTDI usb connection:

```
'UUU'
```

I would like to receive this as a byte array of

```
[85,85,85]
```

In Python, this I would convert a string to a byte array like this:
    [ord(c) for c in 'UUU']

I've looked around, but haven't figured this out. How do I do this in Visual Basic?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

depends on what kind of encoding you want to use but for UTF8 this works, you could chane it to UTF16 if needed.

```
Dim strText As String = "UUU"
Dim encText As New System.Text.UTF8Encoding()
Dim btText() As Byte
btText = encText.GetBytes(strText)
```

Answer (score 9):

Use the [`Encoding`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.encoding.aspx) class with the correct encoding.

C#:

```
// Assuming string is UTF8
Encoding utf8 = Encoding.UTF8Encoding();
byte[] bytes = utf8.GetBytes("UUU");
```

VB.NET:

```
Dim utf8 As Encoding = Encoding.UTF8Encoding()
Dim bytes As Byte() = utf8.GetBytes("UUU")
```